# Positive/Negative Feedback from Amazon Lex/CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, feedback

Please forgive the completely noob question.

Background: I am not a developer - at best a hobby programmer who has enough knowledge to be dangerous/useful to my superiors. The AWS/Cloud expert at my company just left, gave me a 30 minutes whirlwind tour of AWS and said I'm now the expert...

AWS Cloudformation allows me to provide (basically) a "user" utterance that signifies Positive/Negative Feedback from the user of the bot: WebAppConfNegativeFeedback WebAppConfPositiveFeedback.

How do I process those utterances to provide useful information to improve the bot's responses?

It's stateless, so I'm not sure how to grab the context of the question and feedback to notify our company that some question provided a bad answer (good answer not so important.)

Any help you can provide, at least to point to me how to interpret this information is more than welcome. I hate feeling like a fish out of water...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there and sorry to hear about your predicament.

AWS Cloudformation is a tool set that allows a developer to script the creation of resources; Cloudformation itself is not processing your user's requests.

As you've alluded to, AWS Lex is the service that is used to interact with users.

Here's a link to the [Getting Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-console.html) guide which I hope will help you get a better understanding of just how Lex works so that the rest of this answer makes more sense.

Essentially Lex uses a combination of intents with slots to complete a task. An intent uses utterances as an entry point to understanding what action a user wants to take while slots are used to collect the detail surrounding that action.

As an example, we could have an utterance "set my alarm clock" that activates an intent called `SetAlarm`. We then need to ask the user for the time that they'd like the alarm to be set for. This value is store in a slot of type date.

We then harness the power of AWS Lambda functions to 'fulfill' the intent. In this case, we will use the given information to set the alarm at the user's specified time.

With regards to your scenario, I am making an assumption that you have two fields called `WebAppConfNegativeFeedback` and `WebAppConfPositiveFeedback` somewhere in your Cloudformation script. These contain positive and negative utterances respectively. Again, making an assumption then that these fields are used to either build a Lex bot or it could be that these values are used in a supporting Lambda function to categorise the utterance as either positive or negative.

If it is a case that you have a Lambda function, you should be able to use that function to fire all another process should it be determined that the user's interaction was negative. That process could be an email to a support team etc. The Lambda function would have the conversation state passed in as an argument. You could interrogate this argument to get the context of the conversation.

Please provide more insight if you can so that a more specific answer can be provided.

Comment: That is pretty much the scenario. I believe what I was missing was that the conversation state also gets passed in the json to Lambda. So I should be able to access the state and determine the utterance the user typed before providing feedback on bot's response.

Basically, I'd have an Intent "GiveFeedback" which matches with the utterances from the WebAppConf...Feedback parameters. Process that intent with a Lambda to pull the conversation state from the json sent to Lambda, pull out the user-typed utterance and send it to the team to process the negative feedback. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: I guess I need to find out more about Conversation State in the JSON. Is that the correct search term for it, or should I look with another phrase? And thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you're on the right path. The JSON object passed through to the Lambda will contain the user's raw utterance as well as Lex's calculated value. You will also see the slot values that have already been captured and stored. Your `GiveFeedback` intent could have a slot with two synonyms - one for positive and one for negative and the values from the `WebAppConf###Feedback` parameters will form the two enums for positive and negative respectively. Check JSON formats here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html#lambda-input-format